# run batch files with setsid

Tags: command-line, scripts, batch

I want to run many tasks which are defined is a batch file, for example

**task.sh**

```
for i in 1 2 3 4 5
do
    setsid python main.py 1>data/${i}_a.log 2>&1
    sleep 3
done
echo "OK 1"


for i in 1 2 3 4 5
do
    setsid python main.py  1>data/${i}_b.log 2>&1
    sleep 3
done
echo "OK 2"
```

However, when I run `task.sh`, it got stuck and it seems that it did not run. How can I fix it?

Comment: You set it to sleep 3 seconds every iteration. Is that why it's taking so long?

Comment: Remove `1>data/${i}_a.log 2>&1` and you might see error messages on your screen.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Thank you, but there are no errors. I think in shell, the `setsid` can not make it run in the background and only the former process exits can the later process run. When I run for loop in command and it can run.